# Make a grid of four divs expand to match the tallest height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid layout that sizes all child divs to match the tallest div in the group. For example, I have a 2x2 grid, with each div in the grid containing some text. The div that contains the most text is tallest, and should push the height on the other 3 divs to match.

I can get the div heights to match on each row using `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`, but I need all rows to match in height.

Is this possible to accomplish with CSS, or will I need to resort to jQuery?

```
<section class="grid two">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>The top left div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>The top right div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>The bottom left div</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>The bottom right div</p>
            <p>this has more text, and should casue the rest to strecth to match its height.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my current CSS is:

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-directon: column;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}

.grid > div > div {
    background: #EEE;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g41xas6w/

---

**Update 1:** I can't used a fixed height for two reasons:

1. The client will be able to edit this text, so I can't always know what the height will be.
2. This is a responsive site, so I'd have to do a whole bunch of breaks to ensure that things are always displaying at the correct height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Please see the link above.  These guys have created a jQuery plugin to achieve the effect you are after.

Comment: Thanks, I may end up having to use this (even though I'd prefer CSS). At least this is already responsive!

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `height` tag in the `.grid > div` with for example `200px` it will all be `200px`

```
.grid > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-directon: column;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could use a fixed height, but as i said I need this to expand to fit the tallest text, not a fixed height. I've updated my original question with some details on why I can't use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would work only for the 4 DIVs in a single horizontal line. Change the width and look! If you require the 2X2, the dynamically getting the height of all 4 to be same is not possible with only CSS. You need to either use script to control it or have a height set which would stop being dynamic!

Comment: Yea, I'm thinking I'll have to go a script route, which I'm not too happy about. I'll keep the question open a while longer to see if anyone has any creative ideas. Thanks.